# Html table to pdf tutorial doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I'm following this tutorial to save my html table to pdf. I tried it first with my own table (who is created by ajax - database). didn't work.. Then I tried to do it with the table in the tutorial but that even didn't work..

tutorial: http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php

my code..

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/tableExport.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.base64.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/sprintf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/base64.js"></script>

   <title>Melkerhei</title>

   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
   <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
   <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
   <link href="bootstrap/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
</head>
<html lang="en">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="adminLvl" style="display: none;">true</div>
  <body onload="var k1=window.setTimeout('getCurrentUser(\'get\');', 0); var k7=window.setTimeout('orderAdmin(\'overview\', \'-1\');', 500);">

     <div id=navbar></div>  
        <div class="container">
            <div>
          <h1 style="padding-bottom: 20px;">Bestellingen</h1>
         <table id="customers" class="table table-striped" >
    <thead>         
        <tr class='warning'>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>%ge</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Chinna</td>
            <td>1,363,480,000</td>
            <td>March 24, 2014</td>
            <td>19.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>1,241,900,000</td>
            <td>March 24, 2014</td>
            <td>17.4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>United States</td>
            <td>317,746,000</td>
            <td>March 24, 2014</td>
            <td>4.44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Indonesia</td>
            <td>249,866,000</td>
            <td>July 1, 2013</td>
            <td>3.49</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brazil</td>
            <td>201,032,714</td>
            <td>July 1, 2013</td>
            <td>2.81</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
     </table> 
                   </div>
                   <button onClick ="$('#customers').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});">topdf</button>
              <div id="footer" style="clear:both;"></div>
         </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript ================================================== -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/user.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/logout.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/orderAdmin.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#header").load("header.html"); 
      $("#navbar").load("navbaradmin.html"); 
      $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function setName() {
        var user = document.getElementById("currentUser");
        document.getElementById("userLabel").value = user.childNodes[0].textContent;            
    }
   </script> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `didn't work` - do you get any errors in your developer tools console? developer tools network tab? any hint of any errors anywhere?

Comment: How about giving us some description of what's happening? Do you get any errors? What's not working? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: I take it you have all these files in these folders (relative to the main html document) on your server: `javascript/tableExport.js` 
`javascript/jquery.base64.js` 
`jspdf/libs/sprintf.js` 
`jspdf/jspdf.js` 
`jspdf/libs/base64.js` 
`bootstrap/bootstrap.css` 
`bootstrap/jumbotron.css` 
`bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js` 
`javascript/user.js` 
`javascript/logout.js` 
`javascript/orderAdmin.js` 
`header.html` 
`navbaradmin.html` 
`footer.html`

Comment: @JaromandaX : yes al the js files are in the correct place. All files get "ok" in my network bar in google chrome. When i click the button there nothing happens..

Comment: `When i click the button there nothing happens` - where is "there" - on the site you linked to, or your site?

Comment: wait - are you saying that you get nothing happening on the authors demo site?

Comment: On my screen, in the network tab, when i'm testing..